# Responsive design css dom element manipulation

Tags: html, css, dom, responsive-design

I have div field including a input element and a label element. Both are display: block

```
<div class="cf-full">
    <input id="a" >
    <label class="helptext"</label>
</div>
```

So in normal view, the input field will come first. However, i want the layout to be responsive, so that in mobile the label will come first.

I know this DOM manipulation can be achieved by javascript easily. But is there a way to achieve the reverse DOM elements order by pure css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works

```
div {
    display:table;
}
input {
    display:table-footer-group;
}
label {
    display:table-header-group;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/v8xTC/

Comment: This is wizardry! GJ :)

Answer (score 1):

yes it is: you are trying something like this: (you can resize the viewport in jsfiddle to see what happens)  http://jsfiddle.net/SuWLr/

```
<style type="text/css">
.cf-full input,
.cf-full label{
    float:left;
}
@media all and (max-width: 300px){
    .cf-full input,
    .cf-full label{
        float:right;
    }
}
</style>

<div class="cf-full">
    <input id="a" />
    <label class="helptext">Label</label>
</div>
```

**UPDATE:** after the coment as it wasn't clear to me to have the label change from above to underneath (up/down) so maybe this helps.

Something similar with some positiong styles: http://jsfiddle.net/SuWLr/1/

```
.cf-full {
    position:relative;
}
.cf-full input,
.cf-full label{
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
}
.cf-full input {left:0;top:20px;}
.cf-full label{left:0;top:0px;}

@media all and (max-width: 300px){
    .cf-full input {left:0;top:0px;}
    .cf-full label{left:0;top:20px;}
}
```

Comment: Something similar, but instead of right to left, i want to change to from up to down. So float is not very applicable here

Comment: @IanClark cleaner? but the label is not from up to down which is what the OP would like to have

Comment: I mean to say that until you want to flip the elements (under mobile view, say) then your elements needn't be `position: absolute`. Also, you don't need to set the `left: 0` values. If the OP wants them the other way around then just change it from `max-width` to `min-width`

Comment: @IanClark I agree, was sure the OP wanted the reverse (label above input) already in normal view.. left:0; is there to give the OP an idea how easy he could change it